# My program has no error but does not display the required username and distance from driver as it should

Tags: ios, swift

**Here is the class to be called:**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Requests {
    private var _username:String!
    private var _key:String!
    var distanceFromDriver:Double! = 0.0
    private var _latitude:CLLocationDegrees!
    private var _longitude:CLLocationDegrees!
    private var _location:CLLocation!
    private var _driverLocation:CLLocation!

    var username:String {
        return _username
    }

    var key:String {
        return _key
    }

    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees {
        return _latitude
    }

    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees {
        return _longitude
    }

    var location: CLLocation {
        return self._location
    }

    init(uid:String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, driverLocation:CLLocation, tView: UITableView) {

        self._key = uid
        self._driverLocation = driverLocation

        if let lat = dictionary["Latitude"] as? Double {

            self._latitude = lat

        }

        if let long = dictionary["Longitude"] as? Double {

            self._longitude = long

        }

        if let email = dictionary["Email"] as? String {

            self._username = email

        }
        let riderLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self._latitude, longitude: self._longitude)
        self._location = riderLocation


        let distanceInKM = _driverLocation.distanceFromLocation(riderLocation)
        let miles = (distanceInKM / 1000) * 0.62137
        self.distanceFromDriver = miles
        tView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

**Here is the class that need to retrieve the one above:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import FirebaseAuth


class DriverVC: UITableViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



    var requests = [Requests]()
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cell", bundle: nil),
                                   forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.requests.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if self.requests.count >= 1 {
            self.requests.sortInPlace({$0.distanceFromDriver < $1.distanceFromDriver})

            cell.textLabel!.text = String(format: "%.01f \(self.requests[indexPath.row].username)", self.requests[indexPath.row].distanceFromDriver)

        } else {
            self.requests = []
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: From which language have you copied that code? Read only properties with private backing variables as constants are ridiculous in Swift. Just use `let` !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, buy my follow-up is: is anything displaying (i.e. username/distance is not displaying, is anything else displaying? If you insert `print()` statements in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do you notice that getting called?

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView
    print("Rice for me")
    return 1
    }
    
    numberOfRowsInSection
        print("Beans for me")
        return self.requests.count
        
    }
    
    
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
        print("Meat for me")
            
            

    
 ***** Above action printed ********
    
    Rice for me
    Rice for me
    Beans for me
    Rice for me
    Beans for me
    Rice for me
    Beans for me

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView
        print("Rice for me")
        return 1
    }
    
    numberOfRowsInSection
        print("Beans for me")
        return myarray.count
        
    }
    
    
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
        print("Meat for me")
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item]
        
        return cell    }

   let myarray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"] 

        super.viewDidLoad()
Rice for me
Rice for me
Beans for me
Rice for me
Beans for me
Rice for me
Beans for me
Meat for me
Meat for me
Meat for me

Comment: So if I call my array value that I placed above viewDidload on same tableView controller, it prints everything  including those of the cellForRowAtIndexPath and also displays the values on the segue view controller as I want it to.  but, If i call from a separate class, it doesn't print anything below cellForRowAtIndexPath and does not show anything on the segue View controller.

Comment: how can I use struct and public rather than class and private if that can do the trick or getter and setter. is anyone able to code it the right way for me please.

Comment: I noticed that requests is empty when I ran:        if requests.isEmpty {
            print("Empty")
        }else{
            print("Not Empty")
        }
any one has a solution to this?

Comment: I believe the issue is that: var requests = [Requests]() is not pulling any data. I have tried var requests = Requests() but it is giving an error msg.  Missing argument for parameter 'uid' in call. anyone has a solution please?